# Bootstrap Carosel dosen't work when I add it to full webpage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, testimonials

Help I have a Carousel that works on its own but when I add it to my webpage that I'm creating it stops working completely. I have provided some links... I'm using bootstrap 4 to build the website.

```
         (https://jsfiddle.net/WebiSS/okzjdzw4/2/) - Carousel on its own 


          (https://jsfiddle.net/WebiSS/tbo2h5cy/) - Carousel on webpage 






    <section class="testimonials py-5 text-white px-1 px-md-5 margin-top-xl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="pt-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Our Customers Are Seeing Big Results</h2>

        <div class="carousel-control testimonial-carousel-controls">
          <div class="control d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center prev mt-3"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
          <div class="control d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center next mt-3"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

          <div class="testimonial-carousel">
            <div class="h5 font-weight-normal one-slide mx-auto">
              <div class="testimonial w-100 px-3 text-center d-flex flex-direction-column justify-content-center flex-wrap align-items-center">
                <div class="message text-center blockquote w-100">"They’ve been consistent throughout the years and grown together with us. Even as they’ve grown, they haven’t lost sight of what they do. Most of their key resources are still with them, which is also a testament to their organization."</div>
                <div class="blockquote-footer w-100 text-white">Bill, OneBlood</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h5 font-weight-normal one-slide mx-auto">
              <div class="testimonial w-100 px-3 text-center  d-flex flex-direction-column justify-content-center flex-wrap align-items-center">
                <div class="message text-center blockquote w-100">"Miami Beach Visitor and Convention Authority uses Solodev to craft a website capable of representing its diverse residents. The website features a newsroom with the latest events, an interactive calendar, and a mobile app that puts the
                  resources of VCA at a user’s fingertips."</div>
                <div class="blockquote-footer w-100 text-white">Jim Joe, WebCorpCo</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h5 font-weight-normal one-slide mx-auto">
              <div class="testimonial w-100 px-3 text-center  d-flex flex-direction-column justify-content-center flex-wrap align-items-center">
                <div class="message text-center blockquote w-100">Solodev is a great company to partner with! We are extremely happy with the software, service, and support.</div>
                <div class="blockquote-footer w-100 text-white">Jim Joe, WebCorpCo</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```